# How to map following directory to a url using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache2.2

I have few top level directory which contains sub directories e.g www which are treated as webroot ( for each subdomain e.g)

```
htdocs/myapp/admin/www     --- vhost subdomain admin.mysite.com 
htdocs/myapp/forum/        --- no sub domain 
htdocs/myapp/members/www   --- vhost subdomain members.mysite.com
htdocs/myapp/frontend/www  --- vhost subdomain frontend.mysite.com
```

I just wonder if its possible to access forum from each domain using .htaccess defined under each www directory e.g

```
admin.mysite.com/forum
members.mysite.com/forum
frontend.mysite.com/forum
```

I am searching for a solution that should ONLY work with .htaccess ( not  with symblink etc )

Thanks for you kind support

Comment: You can create symlink in each subdomain and allow following of symlinks or create an alias or rewrite rule in each vhost configuration

Comment: not possible with .htaccess ?

Comment: It is, but you need to update configuration for each subdomain - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create following rewrite rules in each subdomain root .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/forum/$1
```

Notice, the `/forum` has to be accessible via some URL first... w/o this, there is no way how to show the content using `.htaccess`

Comment: plz check my question I need a way to handle that from .htaccess if possible. thanks

Comment: @sakhunzai Sorry, see the updated answer using rewrite engine

Comment: that still not working. One of the issue is that `htdocs/myapp/` directory is not visible as each of sub directory is mapped on one of sub domain. e.g www so www.example.com/forum is not mapped to any thing

Comment: it seems I have only one option ,that is a sub domain for a forum

Comment: @sakhunzai The `/forum` has to be accessible via some URL first... w/o this, there is no way how to show the content using `.htaccess`

Comment: plz update your answer with your last comment , I ll accept it